# Count columns in a HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html, count, html-table

I have a basic string with holds a html table. The table looks like this:

```
<TR>
    <TD>asdf, dfg</TD><TD>0915</TD><TD>0945</TD><TD></TD><TD>15</TD><TD>45</TD><TD></TD><TD>1315</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>asdf, dfg</TD><TD>0915</TD><TD>0945</TD><TD></TD><TD>15</TD><TD>45</TD><TD></TD><TD>1315</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>asdf, dfg</TD><TD>0915</TD><TD>0945</TD><TD></TD><TD>15</TD><TD>45</TD><TD></TD><TD>1315</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>asdf, dfg</TD><TD>0915</TD><TD>0945</TD><TD></TD><TD>15</TD><TD>45</TD><TD></TD><TD>1315</TD>
</TR>
```

How would I use PHP to determine how many columns this table has?

Comment: Do yuou want to count how many td are there inside one tr or inside all the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count `<TD>`'s with [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php). If your string contains more than one row, then count `<TR>`'s and divide total number of `<TD>`'s by number of `<TR>`'s.

Comment: how about counting </td>'s? :P

Comment: First, author did not state that his html may be malformed. Second, to place string "<TD>" inside <td> tag one should replace brackets with corresponding entities, so they won't be caught up by substr_count().

Comment: @Gorgapor - no it can't.  If "<TD>" exists in the string, then it's HTML, and the browser will even attempt to render it that way. If it was text it would look like this "&lt;TD&gt;" which obviously wouldn't trigger a hit with substr_count().  If you did have an actual, errant "<TD>" then your count would be invalid only because the HTML is invalid, not because the algorithm isn't sound.

Comment: Agreed with Peter Bailey, and upvoted. It's much easier than Gorgapor's method, and Bailey's right about the entities.

Comment: Yes, if your HTML is guaranteed valid, this is a good way to do it.

Comment: no, counting `<(/)td>`s will not work, becaue you can always have `colspan` attributes (you could count those too, then it’s probably correct)

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, if you have guaranteed valid HTML, and the table is guaranteed to have equal length rows, you can use simple string manipulation. Split the string on `<tr>`, then count the number of `<td>` in each piece:

```
function count_table_columns($html) {
    $html = strtolower($html);
    $rows = split('<tr>', $html);
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if(!trim($row)) { continue; }
        return substr_count($row, '<td>');
    }
}
```

If there is the possibility of malformed HTML, use an HTML parser to parse the table, then iterate through the `<tr>` nodes, and count the subnodes of type `<td>`.

Here's one HTML parser to consider:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Answer (score 0):

This is simplehtmldom code that basically gets the number of columns in the HTML table

```
$table = $html->find('table',0);

foreach($table->find('tr') as $tr)
               {
                   $c=0;
                   foreach($tr->find('td') as $td) $c++;    
                   if( $c>$largest OR !isset($largest) ) $largest = $c; 
               }
```

$largest will give you column count.